# Android Runtime error while login in

Tags: java, android

New to android development and found this code below which connects to  a mysql database, but seems to fall at runtime after login or register.

package applications.loginandregister;

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.nio.Buffer;

    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

    /**
     * Created by Mitch on 2016-06-04.
     */
    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        SharedPreferences preferences;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        Context context;

        BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
            this.context = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("flag","0");
            editor.commit();

            String urlRegistration = "http://domain.com/LoginAndRegister-register.php";
            String urlLogin  = "http://domain.com/LoginAndRegister-login.php";
            String task = params[0];

            if(task.equals("register")){
                String regName = params[1];
                String regEmail = params[2];
                String regPassword = params[3];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlRegistration);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                    String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regName,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regPassword,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(myData);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    inputStream.close();

                    editor.putString("flag","register");
                    editor.commit();
                    return "Successfully Registered " + regName;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if(task.equals("login")){
                String loginEmail = params[1];
                String loginPassword = params[2];
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                    //send the email and password to the database
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                    String myData = URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginEmail","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("identifier_loginPassword","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(loginPassword,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(myData);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    //get response from the database
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String dataResponse = "";
                    String inputLine = "";
                    while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        dataResponse += inputLine;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    System.out.println(dataResponse);

                    editor.putString("flag","login");
                    editor.commit();
                    return  dataResponse;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        //This method willbe called when doInBackground completes... and it will return the completion string which
        //will display this toast.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            String flag = preferences.getString("flag","0");


            if(flag.equals("register")) {
                Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(flag.equals("login")){
                String test = "false";
                String name = "";
                String email = "";
                String[] serverResponse = s.split("[,]");
                test = serverResponse[0];
                name = serverResponse[1];
                email = serverResponse[2];

                if(test.equals("true")){
                    editor.putString("name",name);
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.putString("email",email);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,LogginIn.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                   display("Login Failed...", "That email and password do not match our records :(.");
                }
            }else{
                display("Login Failed...","Something weird happened :(.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        public void display(String title, String message){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle(title);
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.show();
        }
    }
```

This is what I caught in the logcat

```
applications.loginandregister E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: applications.loginandregister, PID: 11263
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
       at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:164)
       at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:32)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
                                                                                   at applications.loginandregister.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:164)`

Comment: You are trying to access the 3rd element of an array that only has 2 elements. i.e. [0] is the first, [1], the 2nd etc. Perhaps check the result (size of the array) of the split.